# Apache Httpd Build from source: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory

Tags: apache, rhel7, expat-parser

I am trying to build Apache Server v 2.4.38 on RHEL 7.3 and I am using apr 1.6.5, apr-util 1.6.1, and pcre 8.42.

I am running following commands

```
./configure  --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/data/abc/installed/pcre_installed --prefix=/data/abc/installed/httpd_installed  

make
```

While running '***make***' I am receiving error

```
/bin/sh /data/abc/installed/httpd-2.4.38/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -g -O2 -pthread   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/data/abc/installed/httpd-2.4.38/srclib/apr-util/include -I/data/abc/installed/httpd-2.4.38/srclib/apr-util/include/private  -I/data/abc/installed/httpd-2.4.38/srclib/apr/include    -o xml/apr_xml.lo -c xml/apr_xml.c && touch xml/apr_xml.lo
xml/apr_xml.c:35:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
 #include <expat.h>
```

Comment: I cannot do 'yum install expat-devel' because it needs sudo access.

Comment: Why are you building Apache from source if you don't have root access?!

Comment: I want to start httpd server in my machine. Is it possible to install Apache Httpd with rpm package without having root access?

Comment: You cannot make it listen on port 80 unless you have root access, so, you'd only be able to make it work on a port like 8080 (usually, ports below 1024 are reserved).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Download expat-2.2.6.tar.bz2 from  https://libexpat.github.io/.

Extract expat using following command

tar xvjf expat-2.2.6.tar.bz2 -C /path-to-dir

Change to the extracted expat directory.

Build expat using following commands

1. ./configure --prefix=/path-to-expat-installation-dir
2. make
3. make install

While building Apache Httpd from source specify --with-expat

./configure  --with-included-apr --prefix=/path-to-apache-installation   --with-expat=/path-to-expat-installation-dir

Answer (score 11):

### For anyone else coming across this:

OP had to do this because they didn't have `sudo` access. If you do, usually you don't need to download the source of `expat` manually; installing via package manager is way easier. Unless the software you are compiling requires a newer version of `expat` than your RPM repos provide.

So for the RHEL family of OSes you can just do `sudo <dnf|yum> install expat expat-devel`, then proceed with what you were compiling.

Comment: And for Debian/Ubuntu family: `apt install libexpat1-dev`

Comment: On SLES the package name is   libexpat-devel  - so I had to install it as "sudo  zypper install libexpat-devel"  - however that library seems to beget the error described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862122/expat-undefined-reference-to-xml-setelementhandler

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the `expat` library installed?  (Because that's where the [`expat.h`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/lib/libexpat/lib/expat.h) comes from.)

- https://libexpat.github.io/

If you cannot install it globally to the system, I'm sure Apache's `./configure` script must have an option to support a custom location for the library as well.

Comment: Is there a parameter to specify expat library path in ./configure?

Comment: Try `./configure --help | fgrep expat`?!

Answer (score 2):

Tried In Ubuntu
`apt install libexpat1-dev`
For RHEL, I would suggest @cyqsimon's answer

Comment: libexpat1-dev fix my problem on debian