# Why "undefined reference" when the variable is defined and the library is linked?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake

We have a few applications which link to several of our own libraries. I recently added a new application which links to these libraries, and this compiles successfully on Windows.

However, on Linux, I see an "undefined reference" error to a static variable, which of course means that the variable wasn't defined. The error occurs in a library, but only when linked to the new application (the existing applications still link fine).

As you can see, the compiler says that `kAppVersion` is undefined. When actually it is defined in [Version.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/branches/1.4/src/lib/common/Version.cpp), and common is linked (specified in [CMakeLists.txt](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/branches/1.4/src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeLists.txt)). We thought that it may be something to do with `target_link_libraries` ordering, but moving `common` to before `base` (where the error occurs) has no effect it seems. Besides, in other [CMakeLists.txt](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/branches/1.4/src/cmd/synergys/CMakeLists.txt) (e.g. for synergys) the ordering appears to be irrelevant, as this application compiles successfully. This similar question appears to hint that ordering matters, but I haven't had any success with this:

Qustion: [library is linked but reference is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783345/library-is-linked-but-reference-is-undefined)

My only idea is that it could be something wrong in [synergyd.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/branches/1.4/src/cmd/synergyd/synergyd.cpp) or [CDaemonApp.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/branches/1.4/src/lib/synergy/CDaemonApp.cpp) -- but I can't see anything obvious that compiles on Linux but not Windows.

```
Scanning dependencies of target synergyd
[ 90%] Building CXX object src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeFiles/synergyd.dir/synergyd.o
Linking CXX executable ../../../../../bin/debug/synergyd
../../../../../lib/debug/libarch.a(CArch.o): In function `~XExitApp':
/srv/buildbot/synergy/1.4-linux32/build/src/lib/arch/../synergy/XSynergy.h:114: undefined reference to `vtable for XExitApp'
../../../../../lib/debug/libarch.a(CArch.o): In function `CArchAppUtil::exitApp(int)':
/srv/buildbot/synergy/1.4-linux32/build/src/lib/arch/CArchAppUtil.h:31: undefined reference to `XExitApp::XExitApp(int)'
/srv/buildbot/synergy/1.4-linux32/build/src/lib/arch/CArchAppUtil.h:31: undefined reference to `typeinfo for XExitApp'
../../../../../lib/debug/libarch.a(CArchAppUtilUnix.o): In function `CArchAppUtilUnix::parseArg(int const&, char const* const*, int&)':
/srv/buildbot/synergy/1.4-linux32/build/src/lib/arch/CArchAppUtilUnix.cpp:32: undefined reference to `CApp::isArg(int, int, char const* const*, char const*, char const*, int)'
/srv/buildbot/synergy/1.4-linux32/build/src/lib/arch/CArchAppUtilUnix.cpp:37: undefined reference to `CApp::isArg(int, int, char const* const*, char const*, char const*, int)'
../../../../../lib/debug/libbase.a(CLog.o): In function `CLog::insert(ILogOutputter*, bool)':
/srv/buildbot/synergy/1.4-linux32/build/src/lib/base/CLog.cpp:213: undefined reference to `kAppVersion'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../bin/debug/synergyd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeFiles/synergyd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The full code can be browsed from [our repository](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/#svn/branches/1.4/src).

Answer (score 4):

**Real problem in short:** Circular library dependency between `arch` and `synergy`. Also,  `base` actually wasn't linked to `common` library (in the CMakeLists.txt for `base`).

Interestingly, this was caused by a configuration problem in the CMakeLists.txt files for the libraries. This had nothing to do with the CMakeLists.txt for the new `synergyd` application I had added.

The problem was that I did not link the libraries to each other where new calls were added to classes in other libraries. However, it seems that there is now a problem with circular linking.

For example, I could have added...

```
if (UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(arch synergy)
endif()
```

... to CMakeLists.txt in the `arch` library, as `arch` now calls something in the `synergy` library. But this is invalid, since `synergy` already calls something in `arch`.

Apparently this doesn't matter on Windows.

I'm not quite sure though what caused this to start happening, as it's all old code that has been compiling fine before, and still does in other applications. I suspect most likely something to do with the recent removal of boiler plate from CArch, rather than something that CDaemonApp is doing (or maybe even a combination of both).

## Update

Just in case anyone cares ;-) -- I think it is something to do with the relation between the lousy circular library dependency between `arch` and `synergy`, combined with the fact that `CDaemonApp.cpp` wasn't including `CApp.h` -- meaning that it was included at some other point, causing the weird undefined reference errors.

To solve this properly, I have removed the circular dependency, which appeared to be the core of the problem.

## Update 2

The code now fully compiles, hurrah!

I was still seeing one last error (the topic of this question):

```
[ 90%] Building CXX object src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeFiles/synergyd.dir/synergyd.o
Linking CXX executable ../../../../../bin/debug/synergyd
../../../../../lib/debug/libbase.a(CLog.o): In function `CLog::insert(ILogOutputter*, bool)':
/home/nick/Projects/synergy/branches/1.4/src/lib/base/CLog.cpp:213: undefined reference to `kAppVersion'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../bin/debug/synergyd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeFiles/synergyd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This was simply caused by the `base` library not linking to the `common` library. Adding the following code to the CMakeLists.txt file for base fixed this:

```
if (UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(base common)
endif()
```

Still not sure exactly why this started happening, just glad it's fixed.

## Update 3

And here's the commit: [r1354](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/detail?r=1354)

Answer (score 2):

First off, the order of linking does matter, at least with g++. If `A` uses symbols from `B`, then `B` should be mentioned after `A`: `g++ ... -lA -lB`

I also see an `undefined reference to vtable for XExitApp`. This error means that you have a virtual function in `XExitApp` that is not defined. If you don't want to define that function, make it pure virtual by adding `= 0`

Comment: I knew a comment about ordering would come in, which is why I spent so much time on the issue -- as you can see, ordering common before base did not correct the issue.

Comment: Order of linking matters unless the library is linked using ld's `--no-as-needed` option.

Comment: I'm not saying that order of linking does not matter -- please read what I'm saying. I have tried changing the order and it has not solved the issue. The issue may not necessarily be caused by linking order in this instance (unless cmake is changing it somehow).

Comment: @nbolton, did you solve the "undefined reference to vtable" as I said?

Comment: I am looking at the your repository, searched for `getWhat` and don't find its implementation (for class `XExitApp`) anywhere. First solve it (by either implementing it, or adding `= 0`), maybe some of the other ones go away also.

Comment: @Shahbaz, yes indeed, thanks. But the same "undefined reference to `kAppVersion'" error still exists.

Comment: @Shahbaz, take a look at `src/lib/synergy/XSynergy.cpp`

Comment: @Shahbaz, please see my answer for actual solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I noticed was that you're missing "../../lib/synergy" in the `set(inc...` section of `/synergyd/CMakeLists.txt`. Whether this is relevant to the issue I can only guess.

All the link errors you're getting appear to be due to the linker not finding the symbol it is looking for. The usual reasons for this is that the relevant .o file doesn't exist, isn't included in the build, or is compiled improperly.

I would start by cleaning, changing the CMakeList.txt file to match the known working version as much as possible, and rebuilding everything with all compiler/warnings turned on. If that doesn't work (either the same errors or different errors) I would look more closely at what does and doesn't work. You said the Windows build works but the Linux one doesn't. What are the differences between the two and which of those could explain the issue. Similarly with the one similar project that does build properly: what are the differences between the two projects.

Comment: I believe this line is incorrect --> you're missing "../../lib/synergy"

Also, thanks but I understand the linker error, and I realise what *might* be the cause... but as you can see, the solution is not obvious (probably why you aren't able to solve it either).

Comment: Please see my answer for actual solution. Thanks anyway.