# Undefined reference to symbol, even though the library is linked

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

When linking a project I am working on, the linker gives the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../Includes and Libs/lib/libsfml21rca.a(SoundFile.o): undefined reference to symbol 'sf_read_short@@libsndfile.so.1.0'

/usr/bin/ld: note: 'sf_read_short@@libsndfile.so.1.0' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so so try adding it to the linker command line

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

The thing is, libsndfile.so is already linked before libsfml21rca.a, so I have no idea where the problem is.

I'm using Code::Blocks 10.05

Thanks for help in advance

**EDIT:**

Here is the linking command:

> g++ -L"Includes and Libs/lib" -L"Includes and Libs/lib/raknet3_731" -L"Includes and Libs/lib/d3d_new/x86" -L"Includes and Libs/lib/ogg" -L"Includes and Libs/lib/sdl" -LBullet/lib  -o (filename) ...(a whole lot of object files)   -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lpthread -lopenal -ljpeg -lfreetype -lsndfile -lXrandr -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio  ../Bullet/lib/LinearMath.lib ../Bullet/lib/BulletCollision.lib ../Bullet/lib/BulletDynamics.lib "../Includes and Libs/lib/raknet3_731/RakNetLibStaticDebug.lib" "../Includes and Libs/lib/libsfml21rca.a" ../../../../../../home/msabol/Desktop/SFML/sfml2st/sfmlVideo/sfmlVideo/bin/Release/libsfmlVideo.a ../../../../../../home/msabol/Desktop/SFML/sfmlVideo/bin/Release/libsfmlVideo.a

Comment: Try changing the order of linking?

Comment: How exactly am I supposed to change it? Everything is linked in correct order, or at least it seems so.

Comment: Add the command C::B is using to link to your question. (do not add it as a comment!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [library is linked but reference is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783345/library-is-linked-but-reference-is-undefined)

Comment: @H2CO3 also, not duplicated intentionally, I just didn't realize the fault in my linking order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The linker only runs one pass over the library files. So if you have something in Library A that needs something in Library B, you need to have `g++ objects... -llibA -llibB`, if you use `g++ objects... -llibB -llibA` it will fail in the manner you show.

So, in your case, put the `-lsndfile` after `"../Includes and Libs/lib/libsfml21rca.a"`.

(And whose idea was it to put spaces in a the "Includes and Libs" directory - not the best idea I've seen...)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. In my defence, I jumped on this project few days ago, so all the terrible names (there is more of it) were not made by me.
**EDIT:**
Blast damnation, it worked! Thank you, Mats Peterson.

Comment: @Mats frankly, I find the single pass over library more off-putting. There have been countless SO questions like the OP's all because of `ld` linker's limition. Microsoft's `LINK` tool doesn't have this problem for instance. Neither does Embarcadero's ilinker.

Comment: @greatwolf Unfortunately, my job is to make the project run on Unix platforms. So much for Microsoft's `LINK`.

Comment: It is open source, I'm sure a patch would be welcome... Although I suspect that would break things somewhere - or at least if it was really easy to fix without drawback, someone would have fixed it.