# Undefined reference to 'function' error in C when using a library

Tags: linker

I am building some test cases for a library.  There a function is declared and used throughout the library.  lib.a.

I then built up some test cases and implemented those functions, which are not declared in that library in a executable tests.exe

When I build test.exe it gives the error "Undefined reference to ....."  How do I link correctly, I am using Eclipse and CppUnit.  I have linked to the .a library and that .a library is building fine, I just can't link the two.

Comment: Post the build log that contains the linker's error messages.

Comment: There is nothing more than a long list of

"undefined reference to `function'"

Comment: @user1876942 Your question is impossible to answer as stated. You need to provide *concrete* function name that gets unresolved, explain where it is defined, and show your link command line. Your link command line is most likely wrong, perhaps due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7783411/50617

Comment: I just need to know how to link when I have declared a function in a .a library and implemented that in the exe.  How can the .a file know about the implementation in the exe?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Is there a Russian proverb = "You can lead a horse to water but you can't make it drink"?

Comment: Simple solution: move the implementation of that function from the executable to another library?